# Whenever I click the button it gives me last value result not current

Tags: java, android

Whenever I execute data function it stores the correct value of QUERY  but when i get the JSON back. It gives me the result of last value  rather than giving me the result of new value. Something is wrong in function data or function async.

There is no error which that I give you my error log.The QUERY string holds the right value but result is of last string.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
        public static String QUERY = null;
        public static String DATA = null;
        SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;
        Intent speechIntent;
        TextView textView;
        Button button;
        TextView textView1;

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
            setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);
            textView = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.text);
            textView1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.text1);

            requestPermissions (new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 10);

            speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer (this);
            speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener (new RecognitionListener () {
                @Override
                public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onRmsChanged(float v) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onBufferReceived(byte[] bytes) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onEndOfSpeech() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(int i) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
                    ArrayList<String> arrayList = bundle.getStringArrayList (SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                    if(arrayList!=null){
                        textView.setText (arrayList.get (0));
                        QUERY = arrayList.get (0);
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText (MainActivity.this, "Array List is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onEvent(int i, Bundle bundle) {

                }
            });

            speechIntent = new Intent (RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            speechIntent.putExtra (RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            speechIntent.putExtra (RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault ());
        }

        public void start(View v) {
            speechRecognizer.startListening (speechIntent);
        }

        public void data(View v){
            Toast.makeText (this, QUERY, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
            Async async = new Async ();
            async.execute ();
            if(DATA!=null){
                textView1.setText (DATA);
            }
        } }

    class Async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        String line = "";
        String data = "";

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                data=null;
                Log.e("Query in url", MainActivity.QUERY);
                URL url = new URL ("https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?v=20150910&contexts=[]&lang=en&query="
    + MainActivity.QUERY +"&sessionId=bee67580-d05c-47f6-8d64-a6218c3913e1");
                URLConnection httpURLConnection = url.openConnection ();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Bearer 
            CONFIDENTIAL KEY");
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream ();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader (new 
                 InputStreamReader (inputStream));
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine ()) != null) {
                    data += line;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.i ("PROBLEM", "URL");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i ("PROBLEM", "IOEXCEPTIONe");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            MainActivity.DATA = data;
            super.onPostExecute (aVoid);
        }  }
```

Comment: (Why is this *tagged* [tag:exception]? Please check if it meets the tag description.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are calling a `AsyncTask` and right after it access same `Variable` which is modifying inside `AsynCtask`.

```
 Async async = new Async ();
        async.execute ();
        if(DATA!=null){
            textView1.setText (DATA);
        }
```

Here `async` will execute on background thread but Main thread continues So last `DATA` value will set each time .

**Solution**

You better move `setText()` code to `onPostExecute()`.`onPostExecute()`
 runs on Main Thread so you can easily access Ui element inside it .

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute (aVoid);
        MainActivity.DATA = data;
        if(DATA!=null){
            textView1.setText (DATA);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this answer helped you in anyway .Please and upvote the answer . One suggestion do not use static variables if a instance variable can work. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the text before async finishes to execute. You are calling

```
async.execute (); 
if(DATA!=null){ textView1.setText (DATA);
```

`async.execute` returns right away, so DATA still has the old value.
What you have to do is set the textView text in `onPostExecute` function.